# Write a file into a 2D array

Tags: c++

I successfully wrote code to write .dat files that contain textual data into 1D array. However when I tried to develop my code to write these files into 2D arrays, I keep falling in pointers issues. The following code is what I'm trying to fix:

```
while (getline(fin, line)) {
  char* buf = _strdup(line.c_str());
  // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
  int n = 0; // a for-loop index
  int s = 0;
  int m = 0;
  // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
  const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE][MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; 
  char *next_token;
  // parse the line
  token[0][0] = strtok_s(buf, DELIMITER, &next_token); // first token
  //token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
  if (token[0][0]) {
    // zero if line is blank
    for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++) {
      token[m][n] = strtok_s(0, DELIMITER, &next_token);
      //token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER);
      if (!token[m][n]) break; // no more tokens
      m++;
    }
  }
  // process (print) the tokens
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
    for (int j = 0; j<m; j++) {
      cout << "Token[" << i << "," << j << "] = " << token[i][j] << endl;
      cout << endl;
    }
  fin.clear();
  fin.close();
  free(buf);
}
```

Apparently after the first line the first token `token[0][0]` will point to junk as different data will be in `buf`. How to avoid this issue?

Comment: In your printout loop you use `i` up to `n` as the first index, and `j` up to `m` as the second. However, when you read you use `m` as the first index and `n` as the second.

Comment: Also, you read in a loop, but close the file you read from inside the loop?

Comment: And you always increase both `m` and `n` in the tokenization loop, meaning you will set `token[0][0]`, then `token[1][1]`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution may be to use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline` for the tokenizing too:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> tokens;

int current_line = 0;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(fin, line))
{
    // Create an empty vector for this line
    tokens.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());

    std::istringstream is(line);

    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(is, token, DELIMITER))
        tokens[current_line].push_back(token);

    current_line++;
}
```

After this, `tokens` will contain one entry per line in the file, and each entry will be a (possibly empty) vector of tokens.

Comment: Great! but I need to know if I can refer to each element 'token' later on and how can I achieve that if possible? or vector will be cleared after each line from the memory?

Comment: @hawk The vector is declared _before_ the loop, so it will retain all data after the loop is done. If you put it in a separate function, you can return it, or pass it by reference as an argument, or declare it as a member of a class, or even declare it globally if you fancy.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to "copy away" each token, like

```
        if (token[0][0]) // zero if line is blank
        {   token[0][0] = _strdup(token[0][0]);
            for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
            {   token[m][n] = strtok_s(0, DELIMITER, &next_token); 
                if (!token[m][n]) break; // no more tokens
                token[m][n] = _strdup(token[m][n]);
                m++;
            }
        }
```

and free the elements in the token array later on.

Also: you are freeing the `buf` pointer at the end of the file, you will need to free it for each line -- actually, with the logic above, you don't need to call `_strdup()` for `buf`, it can just be `char* buf = line.c_str();`